# Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 not showing breakpoints results

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I added a break point to the below code , it breaks and navigates to the `GameMaster` class, but the description and changes related to the class and it's attributes are not being showed in a window.

```
GameMaster gameMaster = new GameMaster ( die , gameBoard , arrayOfPlayers );
```

I tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding it , rebooting , but non helped.
Any solution please.

Comment: Place it a line below the instantiation, or at the closing brace of the constructor of your class.

Comment: @Lourayad didn't work